# How to check, checkbox checked or not on click

Tags: jquery

How to checkbox checked or not on click

```
$('body').on('click','.beach_access,.parks,.neighborhood_parks',function(e){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                alert("Checkbox is checked.");
            }
            else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
                alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
            }

         });
```

Always "Checkbox is unchecked." alert.

Comment: It already works https://jsfiddle.net/29bkmydy/1/

Comment: how does your html look?

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#checkbox_id').click(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('Checked');
      }
      else{
        alert('Not Checked');
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the newest Jquery library versions you must go for [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to resolve your issue. 
so your code should be written as follows:

```
$('body').on('click','.beach_access,.parks,.neighborhood_parks',function(e){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
     alert("Checkbox is checked.");
  }`enter code here`
  else {
     alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
  }
});
```